# UIButton on a UILable is not getting clicked

Tags: iphone

I have a button which has been added to a UILabel and that UILabel is being added on UIView and finally that UIView has been added to a scroll view.

This is my code:

```
nextBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
nextBtn.frame=CGRectMake(250, 8, 26, 26);           //2626
[nextBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextBtnClkd) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[reviewLabel addSubview:nextBtn];
[middleView addSubview:reviewLabel];
[mScrollView addSubview:middleView];
[self.view addSubview: mScrollView];
```

Now the nextBtnClkd method is not being called on button click.

Please help me.

THanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your UILabel accept interaction events?

```
reviewLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Show your label and middleView code.

```
nextBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
nextBtn.frame=CGRectMake(250, 8, 26, 26);
[nextBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextBtnClkd) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[nextBtn addSubview:reviewLabel];  //Add label on Btn.  
[middleView addSubview:nextBtn];
[mScrollView addSubview:middleView];
[self.view addSubview: mScrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The user interaction of your label is set to NO. So first set it YES.

```
reviewLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```